# laravel 5 select input is not inserting in users table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, forms-authentication

I decided to add a *type* column in the predefined users table

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('type', 50);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and I already set it to fillable so that it can be filled.

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'type'];
```

I also made a select input in my register view to take the value

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="type" id="type">
      <option value="0">Patient</option>
      <option value="1">Doctor</option>
      <option value="2">Nurse</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

but only blank values are added to my *type* column, what do you think is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either remove the `value` attribute or set it equal to the desired value 'Patient'.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="type" id="type">
      <option>Patient</option>
      <option>Doctor</option>
      <option>Nurse</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i did both... still nothing :( this worked for me last time.. but now its just sending blanks

Comment: In your controller try `dd($request->all());` before you save and see what is in there. Also could you post your controller code.